# SQL Server 2008 request example on creating a cursor to loop through records

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does any have experience in creating cursor to loop through a bunch of records? If you do can you provide me with a basic example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have experience with that - that experience being: **don't do it!** SQL is a **set-based** language - think and act in **sets** of data and **avoid** the RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing model

Comment: Shouldnt really be closed. Nice to have a template for cursor in a Q/A

Answer (score 27):

```
declare cur cursor for 
select id from tbl 
open cur
declare @id int
fetch next from cur into @id
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    print(@id)
    fetch next from cur into @id
end
close cur
deallocate cur

-- just replace "tbl" with your table name and "id" with your field name
-- and do whatever you want in begin-end block (now it simply prints the id of each record)
```