# How to pass multiple results of a SQL query through a stored procedure that only allows one parameter at a time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am running a SQL query where I search for all the ID's in a table that have a specific parameter. For this example, let's call it an indicator =  "locked".

*(Sample Data)*

[image]

So I run a query ...

```
SELECT ID FROM tableOne WHERE Status = 'locked'
```

And get this result:

[image]

I now need to pass all of the results gathered from this query, into a stored procedure, which only allows me to pass in a single ID at a time.

Is it possible to run my query, as the parameter for this stored procedure?

Instead of this:

```
exec spDeleteLocked
     @id = 'X1234'
exec spDeleteLocked
     @id = 'G2321'
exec spDeleteLocked
     @id = 'L2312'
```

doing something like this:

```
exec spDeleteLocked
    @id = 'SELECT ID FROM tableOne WHERE Status = 'locked'
```

**If not**: is there a way for me to return the results of the query to the stored procedure, over and over? According to my classmates, this is not possible in SQL.

Comment: This is what CURSORs are for.

Comment: What does your SP return/do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 request example on creating a cursor to loop through records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856518/sql-server-2008-request-example-on-creating-a-cursor-to-loop-through-records)

Comment: How tight is the scope for this?  Can you not just add the select to the original sproc and then join on the results?  Is that result list used for other functionality after the mentioned sproc is called?  Lots of unknowns that will lead to lots of possible answers.  Loops and cursors will work, changing the input parameter is better if you don't have to fix a ton of calling locations, simply encapsulating the select query in the sproc that does all the work is best if you don't use the results for other work.

Comment: @PeterSmith it removes the ID field from a number of different tables the ID is associated with. I did not create the SP and am rather new to the concept.

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks, I will look into those now and let you know. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @TabAlleman After looking into Cursor creation, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to pass the list without editing my stored procedure. Thank you. Wish I could mark this as an answer.

Comment: @Rev, glad it helped.   I commend you on finding a solution with only a nudge in the right direction.    : )

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them in as a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Then use the TVP with an inner join in your query for filtering.

Comment: That would require modifying the stored procedure.

Comment: Why can't you do that?